# Edit different text font on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I am trying to perform edit functions in a RichTextBox on a C# (Windows Forms) application and .NETFramework 3.5. I would like to be able to select any number of text characters from all text present on the RichTextBox and then change targeted font characteristics.

The trouble I have is that on my selected text each characters font properties may be set to different font. In this case the textbox ignores the event that I request.

```
case "Font Size": ComboTool = (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ComboBoxTool)this.RTFUltraToolbarsManager.Tools["Font Size"];
                try 
                { 
                    this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Name, float.Parse(ComboTool.Text), this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Style); 
                } 
                catch { } 
                break;
```

When I do that in my "RTFUltraToolbarsManager_ToolValueChanged", I want to change te size of the selected text and the "this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont" is null.

Do you know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem, which problem you mean?

Comment: When my selected text has characters with different font families, richtextbox edit properties does not work. The SelectionFont is set to null value.

Comment: it should work, show some code

Comment: case "Font Size": ComboTool = (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ComboBoxTool)this.RTFUltraToolbarsManager.Tools["Font Size"];
                    try 
                    { 
                        this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Name, float.Parse(ComboTool.Text), this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Style); 
                    } 
                    catch { } 
                    break;
     
     
When I do that in my "RTFUltraToolbarsManager_ToolValueChanged", i want to change te size of the selected text
and the "this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont" is null.

Comment: ahh, richtextbox is infragistic, I think Infragistic support forum is better place for such questions

Comment: RichTextBox is from System.Windows.Forms. UltraToolsbarsManager is from Infragistics but that is working fine. Instead of that line of code, think on this: 
this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Name, 12.0, this.RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Style)